# Doing stuff for onmouseout in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im try to use this to do things when I get my mouse out of a picture
It does nothing? This worked before . . . why not now?
I can't find any errors or reasons why this woulden't work.

```js
document.getElementById("mb").onmouseout = function() {
  alert("HEY");
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    LyghtServ Network
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Format.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Core.js">
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <h3>
    This site requires JavaScript.
   </h3>
  </noscript>
</head>
<header>
  <div id="nav">
    <img id="mb" src="Header/Menu/MenuClosed.png" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" ondragstart="return false;" onmouseover="" onmouseout="" onclick="MenuButtonToggle()">
    <ul id="MenuItems">
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">A BUTTON!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wrap the code in `DOMContentLoaded` or move the script to the end of the `<body>`

Comment: Remove `onmouseout=""` from your `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code .Its working in your snippet .

Comment: Thats what I mean It worked before perfectly but, now pfttt nothing.

Comment: Same browser same code except for a few changes I added back. . . and it still dosen't work. How?!?!?